# form open Redirecting to the wrong path

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and facing a problem after form submission

```
      <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
      <br/>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
      </form>
      login page url http://localhost/codeig/login/
```

after form submission i am redirecting to the controller verifylogin but it is redirecting as below

```
       http://localhost/codeig/login/localhost/codeig/verifylogin
```

i have the validation code in verifylogin controller

Thanks in advance

```
verifylogin.php

  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {
     function __construct()
     {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
     }

    function index()
  {
  //This method will have the credentials validation
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',        'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
 {
  //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
  $this->load->view('login_view');
  }
   else
   {
   //Go to private area
   redirect('home', 'refresh');
  }

       }

   function check_database($password)
  {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    if($result)
   {
    $sess_array = array();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
    $sess_array = array(
      'id' => $row->id,
      'username' => $row->username
      );
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
      return TRUE;
      }
      else
     {
  $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
  return false;
   }
    }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: can you show controller code also?

Comment: In config file what is `base_url` you have set?

Comment: try <?php echo form_open('verifylogin/index'); ?> also have setuped any routes?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeig/';

Comment: @Gowda keep  it `$config['base_url'] = ''`. CI is smart enough to auto detect it ;)

Comment: @RakeshSharma nope still same http://localhost/codeig/login/localhost/codeig/verifylogin/index

Comment: @karanthakkar yep its working now thanks.little explanation will be helpfull.

Comment: looks like you have redirecting code somwhere try function index() { die('i am in verify login index');

Comment: @Gowda ill post it in a min

Comment: @RakeshSharma its working now when i made config base url empty $config['base_url'] = ''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as from the comment.

your base url is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/codeig/'
```

you forgot to include protocol i.e. `http://`

basic structure of a `base_url` is

1 **Protocol**

2 **Domain**

3 **Path to CI Installation**

if you keep

```
$config['base_url'] = ''
```

### CI will auto detect base_url

Comment: nice answer with description as well +1 for you